# In WinRT MVVM Using Prism how do I listen for a SetProperty notification?

Tags: windows-runtime, prism

I am using Prism for Windows Runtime to help with my MVVM implementation. It has a built in SetProperty command for properties. How do I listen for a property change from within the View Model to make something else happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event and check the name of the property. If you want to avoid string comparisons - you can define a new event and raise it for specific property. It can either be a regular CLR event or an `EventAggregator` one if you want to broadcast it to any interested listeners in the app.